# Closing LibreOffice documents one at a time

Tags: libreoffice

Whenever I close a LibreOffice window (e.g. a Writer document), LibreOffice asks me if I want to save/discard changes/cancel for all the rest of the LibreOffice documents currently open. I find this distracting and error-prone.

Is this standard behavior? If it is, is there any way to change it? I would much prefer that LO took all clients to be independent, to be opened and closed independently. (And if it isn't standard behavior, is this a bug of some sort, or a weird setting I turned on and forgot about?)

I'm running LibreOffice 6.4.0.3 40(Build:3) on an up-to-date Arch Linux box.