# How to close LibreOffice opened file one at a time?

Tags: arch-linux, libreoffice

I find that when I opened multiple files with LibreOffice and I close one, LibreOffice will also close another file.

I want to close the file separately as my question title.
I also find [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568246/closing-libreoffice-documents-one-at-a-time) which currently doesn't have any answer which (I think) have a problem that is related with my question.

Is this is the standard behavior? Or there are some setting(s) that I need to change?

Btw, I use Arch and I installed LibreOffice from Arch `libreoffice-fresh` official package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It's actually pretty simple. LibreOffice will close all opened file if you close it with File -> Exit LibreOffice. Instead you should do File -> Close. My bad I didn't realize it earlier :/ ...